# How to log every command typed into bash and every file operation

Tags: bash, logs

I would like to log every command typed into bash (by either root or user) as well as every file operation.

The idea is that I could write tools that could interrogate this log file and provide very useful information.

For example it would be great to list all commands ever typed, one per line, with "- - -" for 8-24h time gap and "= = = e.g. 24 June 2014 = = =" for >24h gap. If it also eliminated duplicates within a "= = =..." session even better!

That would mean that whenever I accomplish some task such as "upgrade flask/mod_wsgi/apache to Python 3.x" a record is left behind, a trail I can pick up if I have to do the same thing six months later.

To the same end it would be very nice to see what file system changes occurred after installing a particular package.  That would let me know where the config files got put.

PS I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Are you aware of the `history` command? Does it provide what you need?

Comment: Unfortunately `history` tends to eat information, e.g. simultaneous shells, broken pipe, buffer overrun, etc.

Comment: That's what auditing is  for:  http://linux-audit.com/configuring-and-auditing-linux-systems-with-audit-daemon/

Comment: Yeah this is the exact problem `auditd` is intended to resolve. You can audit all `execve` syscalls to get the commands and the watch particular files or monitor the file I/O related syscalls if you truly need to see every single operation.

Comment: Although it sounds like you're just trying to figure out what a binary package is doing. Have you thought of [just extracting the files from the .deb file](http://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-download-and-extract-a-deb-package-on-ubuntu-or-debian-linux/)? That's probably going to get you want you're actually interested in without doing anything elaborate.

Comment: This may help: [checkinstall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CheckInstall), which uses LD_PRELOAD to monitor all filesystem operations, then (you may not need this part) creates an installable package consisting of everything that was added.

Comment: Simultaneous shells are not an issue if you [set up your history properly](http://superuser.com/q/575479/151431) (also read my answer which clarifies that those should be in `~/.profile`). If that would work for you, let me know and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is not as comprehensive as real accounting, and it can be undone easily by a user, but assuming it doesn't have to be a real accounting system and that both BASH and rsyslog are in use, edit the system-wide BASH RC file:

```
sudo -e /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Append to the end of that file:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='RET_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RET_VAL]"'
```

Above, `logger` records the time, user, command, and command return value. Set up logging for "local6" with a new file:

```
sudo -e /etc/rsyslog.d/bash.conf
```

And the contents...

```
local6.*    /var/log/bash_commands.log
```

Restart rsyslog:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Log out. Log in. Log rotation:

```
sudo -e /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
```

There is a list of log files to rotate the same way...

```
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
[...]
/var/log/message
```

Add the new bash-commands log file in that list:

```
/var/log/bash_commands.log
```

Save and restart/reload rsyslog. (The rotation will eventually overwrite log files, so more thought or configuration may be needed.)

To see all the files that a package has installed:

```
dpkg-query -L [package_name]
```

So you could execute something like that when you install software.

```
dpkg-query -L abc-package > /var/log/files_abc-package.log
```