# Use PROMPT_COMMAND to echo to custom bash history file

Tags: bash, command-history

I executed the command below in a BASH shell.

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "$BASH_COMMAND" >> $HOME/my_bash_history'
```

but everytime I type something in the shell and hit return, I just get one more line my_bash_history file which fills up with:

```
echo "$BASH_COMMAND" >> $HOME/my_bash_history
echo "$BASH_COMMAND" >> $HOME/my_bash_history
echo "$BASH_COMMAND" >> $HOME/my_bash_history
echo "$BASH_COMMAND" >> $HOME/my_bash_history
echo "$BASH_COMMAND" >> $HOME/my_bash_history
echo "$BASH_COMMAND" >> $HOME/my_bash_history
```

anybody know why that's happening?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I don't think this is a duplicate. The asker here is using single quotes (as far as I can tell, correctly), but the action is _not_ being interpolated at use-time as explained and expected in the "duplicate".

Answer (score 2):

As Rui pointed out, "Anything inside <kbd>'</kbd> is not evaluated." Or, as stated by the BASH manual,

> Enclosing  characters  in  single  quotes  preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.

As a solution to accompany the answer, one way to record the history with `PROMPT_COMMAND` follows.

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//") >> $HOME/my_bash_history'
```

Comment: thanks - seems weird that I have to look into history to get the previous command - since there is no new command yet, I would think $BASH_COMMAND would still be set to the previous command? idk

Comment: can you explain what the sed command is doing? I can accept once I know for sure what it's doing thx

Comment: from what I can tell, this won't let me capture the PID of the previous command or the exit code, or anything useful like that - although perhaps there's an option to put that into the bash history?

Comment: I remember answering different questions that might provide more clues. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518909/logging-shell-activity and  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207813/how-to-log-every-command-typed-into-bash-and-every-file-operation/.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Oops... missed your `sed` question. I may have incorrectly surmised that you are using Linux; but, in Linux, at least, the `sed` command removes the command history number and the white space surrounding the command history number.